# I can't execute kubectl inside a docker container to access Minikube API (MacoS Docker as hypervisor)

Tags: hyperledger, kubectl, minikube

I am using minikube (Using MacOS docker as Hypervisor) to test Hyperledger Bevel using the standard documentation.
minikube runs OK and I can connect to it running kubectl from the Mac, but in the process I need tu run a Docker not (minikube pod) to execute some kubectl commands (in the docker, notin MacOS). .
As of Bevel documentation, I should get the minikube server from ~/.kube/config file, which is

```
server: https://127.0.0.1:57042
```

(This is the API endpoint that kubectl uses in the MacoS host, which works ok).
The problem is that inside the docker, 127.0.0.1 it does not connect to the minikube API.

I have tried:

```
~ ➤ kubectl get services -o wide -n default --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE    SELECTOR
default       kubernetes       ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  9h     <none>
```

But that IP, 10.96.0.1 and port (443) won't work from the Docker either:

```
kubernetes client initialization failed: Get \"https://10.96.0.1:443/api?timeout=32s\": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
```

How can I know which is the ContainerIP (and port) of the endpoint that Kubectl running inside a docker I should use? (If possible... maybe minikube is not visible for standalone docker instances

Comment: Have you checked this [git issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2479#issuecomment-373634752)?Did it resolve your issue?

Comment: I have clarified the question. I think it was not clear enough. It is not related to that issue, but thanks!!!!!